# How to create a symmetric table in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to create a symmetric table in Excel for my project, to work as a "cabling matrix". On each cell, I would paint it as my color coded cables, and then would know what goes in which port.

I've looked for other alternatives, as in other type of diagrams, but don't find much on cabling support materials. So I've thought about creating this symmetric table.

- I want the horizontal headers to be exactly the same as the vertical ones;
- I'd love if the columns and rows could be fitted to (both vertical and horizontal) header words - but it seems the auto-fit with/height doesn't always work, or I don't know how to do it;
- Since it's symmetric, only half of the table contains valuable information.

I've started doing it everything by hand: [image]

The horizontal part is (relatively) auto adjusted, expcept for the columns where the 2nd row ("Secondary PSU", for example) is wider than the 3rd row ("I" and "O").

But then to make it all again for the vertical part, every hand made adjustment.. is just too much. Makes me think I've bitten more than I could chew.

Any ideas?

Do you guys know any templates or something? I'm sure there's a way. I'm also doing a transpose copy-paste for the vertical part, surely there's someway to make it dynamic.